# Combine mapped commands in other mapping

Tags: nmap

How do I combine mapped commands into another mapping?

For example, I have two mapped commands, each of which enters a bracketed string at the end of the current line, and then leaves the cursor on the line following:

```
nmap <leader>wtf A<Tab>(wtf!?)<CR><ESC>l
nmap <leader>eh A<Tab>(eh?)<CR><ESC>l
```

Each of them work as expected individually.

When I reuse them both in another mapping, the new command executes the first but not the second:

```
nmap <leader>c1 \wtf\eh
```

I tried using `<leader>` at the head of each sub-command. It again, executes the first and not the second.

```
nmap <leader>c2 <leader>wtf<leader>eh
```

I tried also separating the sub-commands with a `<bar>` operator in the new mapping. That does the same thing: executes the first but not the second.

```
nmap <leader>c3 \wtf<bar>\eh
```

A regular bar operator generates an error upon its definition (`E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &`):

```
nmap <leader>c4 \wtf | \eh
```

How can I combine these simple commands by invocation in another mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Both:

```
nmap <leader>c1 \wtf\eh
```

and:

```
nmap <leader>c2 <leader>wtf<leader>eh
```

are correct. Each comes with its own set of issues (mostly related to the `<leader>` mechanism) but they are fine as far as the problem at hand goes.

The problem is not in the way you combine those mapping together, but in your original mappings themselves:

```
nmap <leader>wtf A<Tab>(wtf!?)<CR><ESC>l
nmap <leader>eh A<Tab>(eh?)<CR><ESC>l
```

which could just as well be simplified to:

```
nmap xx Ax<Esc>l
nmap yy Ay<Esc>l
```

Both end with `l`, for "move the cursor one character to the right", but the cursor is already on the last character of the line so the cursor can't be moved. `l` is thus an error, which prevents the rest of the mapping to be executed. See `:help map-error`.

Those `l`s serve no purpose so you can remove them to fix your problem.